# Can I use custom annotations to classify Java classes?

Tags: java, annotations

1. Is it possible that use self defined Annotation to classify java class into different product function ? (Following are my thoughts)
2. If not, are there any other method to achieve the same purpose in Android project?

Step1: use self defined annotation to make clear java class's function

```
    @SelfDefinedAnnotation( "product-function-a" )
    class MyClass {
        void func() {
           //do something
        }
    }
```

Step2: during building period, generate a mapping file like this

```
   MyClass -> product-function-a
   YourClass -> product-function-b
```

Comment: Use annotations to make a map of value->class(es)?  Sure that's possible.  Just add an annotation handler and have it accumulate in a multimap, then write the values at the end.  It doesn't get you much unless you have other plans beyond that.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure about android (never worked with it), but in pure java its possible for sure.

You should define an annotation with retention policy `SOURCE` and since you're talking about build time, define an annotation processor. This is something that is "hooked" into the compilation process and allows creating such a mapping (I assume you want to store it in some kind of file, maybe *.properties file, or even generate a java source code with these definitions.

The annotation processor is broad topic, there are many ways to register them, so it pretty much depends on how do you build your stuff exactly, but its a general direction.

Please check out [this tutorial](https://www.baeldung.com/java-annotation-processing-builder) it talks about annotation processors, the ways to register them, to associate with your custom annotation and so forth.

One suggestion though, if you're about to generate Java Source class and not just a properties file, this tutorial goes "low level" and tries to prepare the syntax by itself, I suggest using a much nicer (IMO) [Java Poet](https://github.com/square/javapoet) library that will help to generate a proper java code

Comment: How to write the mapping into *.properties file ?

Comment: Annotation processor is invoked for all annotated classes, this is something that you implement. So you access the value of the annotation and the name of the class and write this information to the properties file. This is exactly the mapping you're talking about, right?